# Finding the 'n'th k-permutation of a set, and finding 'n' for a given k-permutation (lexicographical ordering)

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, permutations

Suppose you have a set, and want to order the k-permutations of the set (for example, the permutations of 5 elements of the set {1, 2, 3, ..., 16}). Is there a fast way of finding 'n' (the "lexicographical index") for, say {3, 16, 4, 11, 7}, and a fast way of finding the 5-permutation such that n = 100000?

Answer (score 1):

When you say fast, what do you mean?
If you mean a faster way than actually compute all the k-permutations, you actually can treat the problem as finding some element in a base(here the basis coefficients are gonna be Permutation numbers).For example, if you give me the set $[p]=\{1,\ldots ,p\}$, an integer q and an index i you must iteratively compute $\lfloor \frac{i}{\binom{p-n-1}{q-1-n}*(q-1-n)!} \rfloor+1$ (where $\binom{p-n-1}{q-1-n}*(q-1-n)!$ states because you want to choose the other numbers that are gonna be in the sequence and they have an order)and then decrement i in the residue.
 For example, suposse you want to calculate the 837th 3-permutation of $[16]$. The first element would be $\lfloor  \frac{837}{\binom{16-0-1}{3-1-0}*(3-1-0)!}\rfloor +1= \lfloor  \frac{837}{\binom{15}{2}*2!}\rfloor+1=\lfloor  \frac{837}{210}\rfloor+1=4$
 then you update the i as $837-210*\lfloor  \frac{837}{210}\rfloor=207$
$\lfloor  \frac{207}{\binom{16-1-1}{3-1-1}*(3-1-1)!}\rfloor +1= \lfloor  \frac{207}{\binom{14}{1}*1!}\rfloor+1=\lfloor  \frac{207}{14}\rfloor+1=15$ but you put 4, so it's gonna be 16.
update i as $207-14*\lfloor\frac{207}{14}\rfloor=11$ but because you put 4,it's gonna be 13.
So the 3-permutation in $[16]$ with index 837 is $\{4,16,13\}$.
I think the complexity is gonna be $O(p*q)$.
For the inverse problem its the same Suposse i give $(a_1,\ldots a_q)$, the index of that permutation in $[p]$ is going to be like $(a_1-1)*\binom{p-1}{q-1}*(q-1)!+(a_2-1-[a_1<a2])*\binom{p-2}{q-2}(q-2)!+\ldots+(a_q-1-|\{j:a_j<a_q\}|)*\binom{p-q}{q-q}*(q-q)!$ I think this must be $O(p*q)$ also because of the binomial numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by {j : a_j < a_q }?

Comment: You need to count the numbers that where in position q before you put $a_q$ but you must take care about the numbers you have already put in other positions, that's why you must subtract the cardinal of that set. Indeed, i have a typo the set is $\{j\leq q:a_j<a_q\}$

Comment: Ah alright, so it's the amount of numbers in the first q numbers in the permutation that are smaller than the qth number? So for example using the permutation (9 1 4 6 2 7 8 5 3) with q = 6, |{j <= q : a_j < a_q}| = 4?

Comment: Yes....and yes.

Comment: When you say "... = 15 but you put 4, so it's gonna be 16", how do you know when you should move to the next element of the set? That's the thing I'm having trouble with now. Without skipping elements like this, I end up with "permutations" like (1 1 1 1 1).

Comment: you must iterate over the permutation you are having and compare if the elements are lower than the one you must put.
I mean in the one i show you i have in the first iteration 4, then i have 15, so i iterate in the permutation that i already have and i see 4 is on it. Because 4 is lower i increment by 1 to 15 and get 16. Then i have 12 but 4<12 and 16>12 so i need to carry one and i get 13. Note that is like countintg the  $\{j:a_j<a_q\}$ in the inverse step.